# mobx-state-tree convert optional type to non-optional

Tags: mobx-state-tree

How to convert optional type to non-optional

from `types.optional(types.string)` to `types.optional`
As far as I know this works:

```
const t = optional(types.string); 
delete t.defaultValue
```

But this seems very wrong. Is there a better way?

Comment: Ouch... this *is* so wrong. Care to explain why you would even want to convert optional to non-optional?

Comment: This was a case where I needed to dynamically build a new model from existing model declaration. Further more I wanted to build a same model type and set up all props to be the maybe type. The maybe type and the optional type doesn't play nice together because undefined will always fallback to default value of the optional. The use case was a form component which would contain undefined values and validate those properties on input

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.named(name)` method, which clones the given type, gives it a new `name` and provides a way for you to "extend" it with additional properties, views, actions, or perhaps, overrides of those declared in the original type.

Example:

```
const Square = types
    .model("Square",
        {
            width: types.number
        }
    )
    .views(self => ({
        surface() {
            return self.width * self.width
        }
    }))

// create a new type, based on Square
const Box = Square
    .named("Box")
    .views(self => {
        // save the base implementation of surface
        const superSurface = self.surface

        return {
            // super contrived override example!
            surface() {
                return superSurface() * 1
            },
            volume() {
                return self.surface * self.width
            }
        }
    }))
```